# Открыть видео в mxplayer через intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Вопрос в заголовке. Как?
Пытался

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.trim()));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url.trim()),
                        "application/com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro|application/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
                PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

                if (activities.size() > 0) {
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.trim()));
                    List<ResolveInfo> a = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
                    Log.d("download", title + " " + url);
                    if (a.size() > 0)
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Помимо mx так же предлагает dvget даже если нажимаю запомнить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто указание миме-типа не поможет - приложения подписываются на всё.
Нужно указать явно пакет и активити цели.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.trim()));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url.trim()),
                    "application/com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro|application/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (activities.size() > 0) {
    boolean started = false;
    for (ResolveInfo info : activities) {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = info.activityInfo;

        if (activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.mxtech.videoplayer")) {
            getContext().startActivity(intent.setClassName(activityInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name));
            started = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!started)
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```